# How can I interpret this Python memory profile?

Tags: python, memory

I am running a Python script and I use memray to watch the memory usage. I got the following graph:

[image]

I don't understand the difference between heap and resident size.

I read [here](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/measuring-memory-python/) that resident size is the ram usage, but I don't find information about heap size. Is it the memory that really I need to execute the script? Or is it only the space that Python saves to execute but didn't use?

How can I read this chart?

Answer (score 0):

Python is a language with a garbage collector (GC). The GC reclaims memory from unreferenced objects: data that's no longer being used. First this data is 'marked for deletion', then on the next run the GC de-allocates it from the heap. This is very much not an immediate process. Data that's about to be de-allocated can still be part of your heap.

Depending on your program (you didn't present your code), it's possible the amount of unreferenced objects is much higher than the data of the rest of your program. Based on your graph, I'd guess you have 32 GB of memory available and you saturate it early in the process. You think you're actively using about 4 GB, but for one reason or another you're not discarding your old data fast enough which may hinder the rest of your program. Or not. It's worth profiling your code to check whether there's actually a problem here.

I usually don't recommend this since people tend to prematurely optimize, but it's worth trying whether [explicitly deleting objects](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) (or, more aptly, de-referencing) or invoking the GC manually helps with your memory management. Especially if it turns out you're running into memory bottlenecks. If not all of the data has to be read at once, consider reading it in chunks instead. But at this point I'm guessing at solutions since your program may well require having as much data available as possible.

If there are no bottlenecks though and the program doesn't have to run on machines with lesser hardware (smaller RAM), I'd leave it be. Optimizing for memory efficiency could hurt performance, after all. There's always a trade-off. The graph simply provides you information, it doesn't tell you by itself that there's an immediate problem to fix.

Comment: *"First this data is 'marked for deletion', then on the next run the GC de-allocates it from the heap."* - Where can I read about that? That's not how I remember it. - *"it's worth trying whether explicitly deleting objects"* - How do you do that?

Comment: @KellyBundy Explaining how the GC of Python works would take me as much characters as would fit in the limit of a Stack Overflow answer and still not make sufficient sense. It's an arcane thing, I'm not a GC expert. I do know it varies a bit between Python implementations. Luckily, I don't have to be a GC expert, the question is not about that. The question is about how to read the chart. One of the methods used in CPython is [reference counts](//docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#reference-counts). I could see and find if my O'Reilly explains it better, or you could post a better answer.

Comment: I've tried adding sources, but part of what I wrote is based on a decade of memory from how it was explained to me. If it was explained to me wrongly or I misremember, feel free to explain how *you* remember it.